# Why am I getting IndexError: list assignment index out of range?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to solve the problem with following problem statement:

> You are given an integer array nums and an integer k.
>
> In one operation, you can pick two numbers from the array whose sum equals k and remove them from the array.
>
> Return the maximum number of operations you can perform on the array.
>
> Input: nums = [1,2,3,4], k = 5
> Output: 2
> Explanation: Starting with nums = [1,2,3,4]:
>
> - Remove numbers 1 and 4, then nums = [2,3]
> - Remove numbers 2 and 3, then nums = []
>   There are no more pairs that sum up to 5, hence a total of 2 operations.

I have written following code but it's giving me following error

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
    del nums[right]
Line 14 in maxOperations (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().maxOperations(param_1, param_2)
Line 48 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 58 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Below is the code written by me.

```
class Solution(object):
    def maxOperations(self, nums, k):
        count=0
        n=len(nums)
        left=0
        right=len(nums)-1
        nums.sort()

        while left<right:
            curr_sum = nums[left] + nums[right]

            if curr_sum == k:
                del nums[left]
                del nums[right] #It's showing error here
                count+=1
                left+=1
                right+=1
            elif curr_sum<k:
                left+=1
            else:
                right-=1
        return count
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can actually do this without deleting any elements from the list.

```
def maxOperations(nums, k):
    count = 0
    n = len(nums)
    left = 0
    right = len(nums) - 1
    nums.sort()
    while left < right:
        curr_sum = nums[left] + nums[right]
        if curr_sum == k:
            count += 1
            left += 1
            right -= 1
        elif curr_sum < k:
            left += 1
        else:
            right -= 1
    return count
```

Comment: I want to know why we don't have to delete them because it's clearly stated in problem definition that we have to remove array elements if they match

Comment: If the problem statement allows for counting the pairs and removing elements as valid solutions, then we have some flexibility in how to approach it. We can choose the method that is most comfortable and efficient, since both give us the expected result. 

In many programming scenarios, it's a good practice to choose the most efficient and straightforward approach to solve a problem. In this case, if counting the pairs without modifying the array achieves the same result as removing elements, and it's more efficient, it makes sense to use that approach.